# angular js scope variables lost on redirect from External call

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm currently developing a application using angularjs, i have a requirement to redirect from html page to external url, and the external url will inturn redirect back to the  same page after some manipulation.

On return to the page all variables that's been stored in scope is lost, is there any way to resolve this problem.

Any help on the same is very much appreciated.

Comment: You're leaving the application and coming back...you can set cookies possibly.

Comment: you could use `localStorage` and load the scope on return - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is just temporary data, you can use the Angular $cookies service in any controller to store the data you want to save. See this example: "http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies.$cookies" (click the "script.js" tab for controller example).

After reload, initialize the $scope vars with cookie data. See here for more on initializing scopes: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.mvc.understanding_controller.

I'd be happy to help you live with this - visit https://www.sudonow.com/, choose a tag, and click "Start Session".